# How to filter a date column that is in "INT" format. SQL Error [58]: Query failed: line 13:13: Cannot apply operator: integer <= date

Tags: sql, hive, dbeaver

I have a transaction table that has the date column saved as an INT in the format "yyyymmdd".

I need to run a query that when refreshed only pulls the last 7 days worth of data regardless of when it is run.

I tried using date_parse:

**date_parse(cast(tbl_date as varchar), '%Y%m%d') as Date
**
but when I use the:

**where tbl_date >= date(current_date) - interval '7' day
**

i get an error.

Please help

SQL Error [58]: Query failed : line 13:13: Cannot apply operator: integer <= date

Comment: full 2 digit months and days? so 20230201 would be feb 1st 2023? and not 202321?  why wouldn't you just use format date to convert it to string and then cast it to integer and subtract 7 for your compairison.  Or fix storing dates as integers if it's not too late...

Comment: Try ``where cast(cast(tbl_date as varchar) as date) >= date(current_date) - interval '7' day``

Comment: Please read and make a [mre].

Comment: Thank you for your help. it may not have worked exactly but it opened my mind to a different angle to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'll do it in Postgres, maybe a little bit quicker.

```
... WHERE TO_DATE(CAST(int_date AS VARCHAR), 'YYYYMMDD') >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 days';
```

The idea is to convert the stored format in something you can compare. There are many utilities, feel free to take the ones you prefer.

For example with MySQL you need one extra step:

```
... WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CAST(int_date AS CHAR(8)), '%Y%m%d'), '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Fairly simple but I never thought of it until I read the other answers on here.

```
where date_parse(cast(tbl_date as varchar), '%Y%m%d') > date(current_date) - interval '7' day
```

So in the `where` clause, I used `date_parse` to get the date format and then used interval to select the current day minus 7.